# Changing data type to export using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

So, I've been fighting with what I believe should be a simple problem for the last hour and a half. Essentially, I'm building a list scraped from a website that involves both Names as well as numbers. While scraping them they are stored into a string list. I'm using xlsxwriter in order to build a multisheet workbook with data from multiple webpages. I can't seem to isolate the list items with "numbers" in them and convert them to a floating point. I just started learning Python yesterday so it's very possible I'm just missing something small. I want the numbers to export to the excel sheet as numbers so that they are easier to work with.

I essentially want to differentiate between actual text strings and number strings and convert the strings that contain numbers into floating points. What I've attempted so far is isolating the first character using x[0], x[:0] and x[:1] to test it in an `if` statement shown below. But when I get to that stage of the code while debugging, it is not actually converting it into a floating point number.

```py
# Function to check if string is number and convert
def checknum(x):
    y = x
    x = x[:1]
    if x in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']:
        x = float(x)
        return x
    else:
        return y

# How it's being used in my main program
row = 1
col = 0
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    stats = []
    for td in tr.findAll('td'):
        stats.append(td.text)
    if stats:
        col = 0
        for item in stats:
            checknum(item)
            if isinstance(item, float):
                worksheet.write_number(row, col, item)
            else:
                worksheet.write(row, col, item)
            col += 1
        row += 1
```

Comment: Going through some more debugging, it is converting it to a float, however when I return out of the function it returns the string and not the converted float

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this with XlsxWriter is to use the `strings_to_number` constuctor option. From the XlsxWriter [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html):

> **strings_to_numbers**: Enable the `worksheet.write()` method to convert strings to numbers, where possible, using `float()` in order to avoid an Excel warning about "Numbers Stored as Text". The default is False. To enable this option use:

```py
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_numbers': True})
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something small like that. I figured it out before you replied by adding item = checksum(item), but your way saves me unnecessary code which is obviously better.